# Closed cylindrical can constructed from fixed amount of material. Ratio of height to radius of the can with the maximum volume.

Tags: calculus, optimization

I've seen this question here before, but I am still unclear on the steps that were taken to answer it:

A closed cylindrical can is constructed from a fixed amount of material. Determine the ratio of height to radius of the can with the maximum volume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the radius be $r$, and constant surface area be $1$. For any other surface area value, scale $r$ and the height accordingly. First, the lateral surface are is:

$1 - 2\pi r^{2}$

So the height is the lateral surface area divided by the circumference, or:

$\frac{1-2\pi r^{2}}{2\pi r} = \frac{1}{2\pi r} - r$

This means the volume is:

$V(r) = \pi r^{2}(\frac{1}{2\pi r} - r) = \frac{r}{2} -\pi r^{3}$

We want to find the maximum, so we will find the points where $\frac{dV}{dr} = 0$ and test them.

$\frac{dV}{dr} = \frac{d}{dr}(\frac{r}{2} - \pi r^{3}) = \frac{1}{2} - 3\pi r^{2}$

$\frac{dV}{dr} = 0\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}-3\pi r^{2} = 0$

$\frac{1}{2} = 3\pi r^{2}$

$r^{2} = \frac{1}{6\pi}$

$r = \pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{6\pi}}$

Discarding the negative radius, and using $h$ for height:

$r = \frac{1}{\sqrt{6\pi}} \Rightarrow h = \frac{\sqrt{6\pi}}{2\pi} - \frac{\sqrt{6\pi}}{6\pi}$

$h = \frac{3\sqrt{6\pi}}{6\pi} - \frac{\sqrt{6\pi}}{6\pi}$

$h = \frac{\sqrt{6\pi}}{3\pi}$

$\frac{h}{r} = \frac{\frac{\sqrt{6\pi}}{3\pi}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{6\pi}}} = \frac{6\pi}{3\pi} =\boxed{2}$